# Tensor Product: Boundedness

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products

*This thread is just a note.*

Given Hilbert spaces.

Then boundedness will be inherited:
$$A,B\text{ bounded}\implies A\otimes B\text{ bounded}$$
Especially, the bounds multiply:
$$\|A\otimes B\|=\|A\|\cdot\|B\|$$

Clearly for simple tensors:
$$\|(A\otimes B)(\varphi\otimes\psi)\|=\|A\varphi\|\cdot\|B\psi\|\leq\|A\|\cdot\|B\|\cdot\|\varphi\|\cdot\|\psi\|=\|A\|\cdot\|B\|\cdot\|\varphi\otimes\psi\|$$
But what about arbitrary tensors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This answer is community wiki.*

Take an orthonormal basis:
$$\mathcal{S}\otimes\mathcal{T}:=\{\sigma\otimes\tau:\sigma\in\mathcal{S},\tau\in\mathcal{T}\}$$

Then one has the bound:
$$\left\|A\otimes B\left(\sum_{\sigma\tau}\lambda_{\sigma\tau}\sigma\otimes\tau\right)\right\|=\left\|\sum_{\sigma\tau}\lambda_{\sigma\tau}A\sigma\otimes B\tau\right\|\leq\sum_{\sigma\tau}|\lambda_{\sigma\tau}|^2\|A\sigma\otimes B\tau\|\\=\sum_{\sigma\tau}|\lambda_{\sigma\tau}|^2\|A\sigma\|\| B\tau\|\leq\|A\|\|B\|\sum_{\sigma\tau}|\lambda_{\sigma\tau}|^2\|\sigma\|\|\tau\|
=\|A\|\cdot\left\|\sum_{\sigma\tau}\lambda_{\sigma\tau}\sigma\otimes\tau\right\|$$
*(In fact, this should be rather taken carefully on finite sums before.)*